# Error in "getDownloadStream". Could not download https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/110/chromedriver_win32.zip

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

i am facing this error while running the code on vs code using npm projects, please guide me on this issue. executing on windows vm ware running on linux server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2RMn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8rMD.png)

i have tried to set proxy in environment variables.

Comment: Sounds like DNS is misconfigured on the machine.